# MongoDB - Database Profiler does not capture queries sent to secondaries replicas

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I'm new to MongoDB and need some help to understand how profiler works with replication in Mongo.

I have a replica set with three instances and the secondaries are used for read only by the application. When I try to profile by connecting to the cluster it only returns commands issued on the primary.
How can I get all commands, especially the ones which were executed on the secondaries replica set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#full-time-diagnostic-data-capture):

> You can enable and configure profiling for individual databases or for all databases on a mongod instance. Profiler settings affect only a single mongod instance and will not propagate across a replica set or sharded cluster.